# How can I disable users from accessing Apache server with an IP address in the URL instead of my domains?

Tags: domains, apache, ip-address, configuration, debian

I have a self-hosted and self-managed web server using Apache 2.4 on Debian. I use many domains on this server and have configured them using *vhosts*.

I want my users to use the domains I configured to connect with, instead accessing the server by its IP address. In other words, users currently can connect to my server using:  `http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/my/web/page` and I want to block that from occurring. Instead I want them to use:  `https://example.com/my/web/page`.

How can I deny access to this webserver's pages when users try using its IP address for the URL?

Comment: Set up a vhost for XX.XXX.XX.XXX which pops up an error, or do that on the default vhost and ensure your customers use an alternative vhost.

Comment: And besides @davidgo correct comment, switch to HTTPS only and problem solved too (because certificate won't match the IP address so browsers won't allow going there).